# How can I make a flex item grow taller (not wider) and overlap another item on hover?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout like this: 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkR6N.jpg)

I tried implementing the product cards using flexbox (i made this [2](https://codepen.io/noobdevvv/pen/jOPPpXm))

```css
.product-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding:5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:500px;
}

.product-container article {
    flex-basis:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(166,159,166,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(166,159,166,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(166,159,166,1);
    position:relative;
}



.product-container article :nth-child(1) {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:25px;
}

.product-container article :nth-child(2) {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:25px;
}

.product-container article :nth-child(1), .product-container article :nth-child(2) {
    color:#7a797f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:1rem;
}

.product-container div {
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    right:44px;
    left:44px;
    background-image: url('https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.active {
    background-color:#f4c60e;
    display:block;
    height:2000px;
    
    
    
}

.active div {
    background-image:url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/5z8OzJ5Ft67duR1ioL9c7yLYl7f5BHIeuohBxCT2qL9E7Ee1Z9f-F2WKitW9pAG75k7fvM5NAc3WRn-Z3GiDTdUyN2M1CD_hmqiBeg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
                    <article class="active">
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="no-margin">
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="no-margin">
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="no-margin">
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="no-margin">
                        <span>Strawberry</span>
                        <span>$2.99</span>
                        <div></div>
                    </article>
                </div>
```

but I have problem creating the yellow card. is there a way to make a flex item grow taller and overlap other flex items on hover? I tried using flex-grow but that will cause the card to grow horizontally and push other cards to the right

is there any better way to create such a layout?

Comment: You can use CSS grids also for making these types of layout. And if you want to hover only one card only, you can make its position absolute. And then place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as commented, `grid` is an option for the main layout, so an element can span through a few rows or colunms, an extra negative `margin` can pull it outside or hover the next row

an example spanning 2 rows :

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 180px));
  grid-gap: 2em;
  padding:1em;
  justify-content: center;
  background:#ddd
}
.item {
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
.item figcaption {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
.item span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply
}
.item form {display:none;}
.item form {
  margin:1em;
  text-align:center;
}
.item form [type="number"]{ width:3rem}
.item:hover , .item.active{
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  position: relative;
}
.item:hover form , .item.active form{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
 <figure class="item">
    <figcaption><span>Item's name</span> <span>Price </span></figcaption>
    <img
      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
    <form><input type="number" 
       min="1"  value="1" > <input type="submit"></form>
  </figure>
  
 <figure class="item">
    <figcaption><span>Item's name</span> <span>Price </span></figcaption>
    <img
      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
    <form><input type="number" 
       min="1"  value="1" > <input type="submit"></form>
  </figure>
  
 <figure class="item">
    <figcaption><span>Item's name</span> <span>Price </span></figcaption>
    <img
      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
    <form><input type="number" 
       min="1"  value="1" > <input type="submit"></form>
  </figure>
  
 <figure class="item">
    <figcaption><span>Item's name</span> <span>Price </span></figcaption>
    <img
      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
    <form><input type="number" 
       min="1"  value="1" > <input type="submit"></form>
  </figure>
  
 <figure class="item">
    <figcaption><span>Item's name</span> <span>Price </span></figcaption>
    <img
      src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_ce4ac41d-c124-49db-8f0f-2f472ee51815?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
    <form><input type="number" 
       min="1"  value="1" > <input type="submit"></form>
  </figure>
  
</section>
```

resources about grid:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/  ,  https://gridbyexample.com/

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column` offers wrapping flex items into empty spaces in container width but with applying `height` to flex container to conatin wrapped items nicely.

**This is an example** but it's not responisve https://codepen.io/DohaHelmy/pen/GRJJXEN

to solve height issue you better use javascript to manipulate different sizes